# Once the Working Cell Bank has been approved for use, the End-Of-Production Cell Bank is .. discarded?

Tags: word-request

From a biotechnological document I'm translating from Russian:

> Once the Working Cell Bank has been approved for use, the End-Of-Production Cell Bank is **discarded**.

Is **discarded** a proper word, or is there some better expression?

Disposed of?

The Russian original uses the word "utilized" (podlezhit utilizatsii - подлежит утилизации) which has the approximate meaning of "disposed of (using the proper procedures)" in Russian.

Comment: Either *discarded* or *disposed of* sounds good to this American English speaker.  Maybe *disposed of* is a little better; *discarded* does sound a little bit like "thrown in the trash", but maybe that's what you mean!  If you really want to keep the sense of "disposed of (using the proper procedures)", "*appropriately* disposed of" is a good choice.

Comment: @stangdon - thank you! No, I did not mean "thrown in the trash". Having read about the way chemicals are disposed of in labs, I doubt that anything is just thrown in the trash there. ^_^

Comment: There might be a better word, but that would depend on what specifically happens to the "End-Of-Production Cell Bank", other than you will just stop using it, such as *set aside* or *throw away*.